# Better way to report locked file in Haskell

Tags: haskell, exception, option-type

I would like to lock a file for exclusive use in Haskell and throw an `IOError` in the case where it is already locked.

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import System.FileLock (FileLock, SharedExclusive (Exclusive), tryLockFile)

-- ...
do
  -- ...
  maybeFileLock <- tryLockFile path Exclusive -- returns Maybe FileLock
  let fileLock = fromMaybe (throwIO (userError "File locked")) maybeFileLock
```

Is there a better way to handle the `Maybe` and just throw an exception if it is `Nothing`? Can I combine these two lines into one?

**N.B.**: One could argue that any combination of these lines will make the intent less clear.

Comment: Your example code is not valid. It has a type error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fileLock <- fromMaybe (throwIO (userError "File locked"))
  <$> tryLockFile path Exclusive
```

but `throwIO :: Exception e => e -> IO a`, so this and your code should mismatch between `FileLock` and `IO a`. Instead:

```
fileLock <- maybe (throwIO (userError "File locked")) pure
  =<< tryLockFile path Exclusive
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I realized the mismatched types when I tried to compile, but was still working through how to fix it.